# get the html of element itself using jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the html of element itself using Jquery html. In the below code I would like get the input element inside div using JQuery as shwon below

```
<div id="content">content div</div>
<input type='text' id="scheduledDate" class="datetime" />

$(function() {

   console.log($('#scheduledDate').html('dsadasdasd'));
    $('#content').html($('#scheduledDate').html());
});
```

**EDIT:**

Can I get the $("#scheduledDate") as string which represent the real html code of the input box, because my final requirement is I want to pass it to some other SubView( I am using backboneJS) and eventually use that html code in a dust file. 
       My original requirement was to get that input field as string so that I can pass it to some other function. I know, if I keep it inside a DIV or some other container, I can get the html by using .html method of JQuery. I dont want use some other for that purpose. I am just trying to get html content of the input box itself using it's id.

Comment: An input doesn't have `html`.  It has `val()`, though.  Is that what you want? Also, if you replace the html of `content`, then the input will be replaced....

Comment: Standard way is to append what you want to a container and use .html on that container

Comment: I want the entire input element itself to be copied inside div element

Comment: @cale_b you're partially right, the input isn't in the #content div though so it will not be overwritten when #content's inner html is replaced.

Comment: *"I want the entire input element itself to be copied inside div element"* - You don't need to get its html to do that, you can use `.clone()` and `.append()`. (It is possible to get its html, but that would take extra steps that you don't need if your goal is just to copy or move it into the div.) @cale_b - An input *does* have html, that is, the html used to *define* the input in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plain or pure JavaScript method, can do better...

```
scheduledDate.outerHTML //HTML5
```

or calling by

```
document.getElementById("scheduledDate").outerHTML //HTML4.01 -FF.
```

should do/return the same, e.g.:

```
>>  '<input id="scheduledDate" type="text" value="" calss="datetime">'
```

if this, is what you are asking for
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5v0x92o/)

p.s.: what do you mean by "calss" ?  :-)

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. Can I use this HTML5 syntax in my backbone view js file? I meant "class", I edited it.

Comment: lol "class" :) it is 
I'm pretty sure the answer is because JavaScript is the backbone of pretty much everything in the web. and for as long as it allows you to handle the element of interest directly as it exists in DOM tree. Because trying to call a dom property of element using jQuery selector such as: `$('#scheduledDate')` will not work because the versions I tried are using some sort of object wrapper, where this dhtml property is not available. So fiddle around a bit...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move the input element into div, try this:

```
$('#content').append($('#scheduledDate'));
```

If you want to copy the input element into div, try this:

```
$('#content').append($('#scheduledDate').clone());
```

Note: after move or copy element, the event listener may need be registered again.

Comment: Can I get the  $("#scheduledDate") as string which represent the real html code of the input box, because my final requirement is  I want to pass it to some other SubView( I am using backboneJS) and eventually use that html code in a dust file.

Comment: @user1614862 see my answer to see how you can get the actual html.

Comment: yes, I have seen your answer and debugged it. It is showing the object representation of the input field. It works perfectly if I append it to DIV, but my original requirement was to get that input field as string so that I can pass it to some other function. I know, if I keep it inside a DIV or some other container, I can get the html by using .html method of Jquery. I dont want use some other for that purpose. I am just trying to get it the html content of input box itself using it's id.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

    var content = $('#content');
    var scheduledDate = $('#scheduledDate');

    content.empty();
    content.append(scheduledDate.clone());

});
```

As the original author has stated that they explicitly want the html of the input:

```
$(function() {

    var scheduledDate = $('#scheduledDate').clone();
    var temporaryElement = $('<div></div>');

    var scheduleDateAsString = temporaryElement.append(scheduledDate).html();

    // do what you want with the html such as log it
    console.log(scheduleDateAsString);
    // or store it back into #content
    $('#content').empty().append(scheduleDateAsString);

});
```

Is how I would implement this.  See  below for a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wzy168xy/2/

Answer (score -1):

This can be done the following ways:

1.Input box moved to the div and the div content remains along with the added input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $inputBox = $("#scheduledDate");
$("#content").append($inputBox);
});
```

2.The div is replaced with the copy of the input box(as nnn pointed out)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $inputBox = $("#scheduledDate");
    var $clonedInputBox = $("#scheduledDate").clone();
    $("#content").html($clonedInputBox);

    });
```

3. Div is replaced by the original input box

   $(document).ready(function() {

   ```
   var $inputBox = $("#scheduledDate");
   $("#content").html($inputBox);

   });
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4485/

EDIT 1: 
to get the input html as string inside the div itself use this

```
$("#scheduledDate").prop('outerHTML')
```

This will give the input objects html as string
Check this js fiddle and tell if this is what you need

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4496/

Comment: Or 3. Append a copy. (OP doesn't make it clear whether to append or copy.)

Comment: Yup added that to the answer

Comment: Neither one of the first two methods you've provided work in the jsfiddle you've provided.

Comment: @sheeldotme edited the first one.And the second one works fine. Just check the fiddle i have provided.it works fine. Made a copy paste error there ont the first.First try it before you knockit. Thanks

Comment: Can I get the $("#scheduledDate") as string which represent the real html code of the input box, because my final requirement is I want to pass it to some other SubView( I am using backboneJS) and eventually use that html code in a dust file.

Comment: @user1614862 Yup. u can use outerHTML for this. Edited the answer.check it out